# Condition number of a matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

[python 2.7 and numpy v1.11.1]  I am looking at matrix condition numbers and am trying to compute the condition number for a matrix without using the function `np.linalg.cond()`.

Based on numpy's documentation, the definition of a matrix's condition number is, "the norm of x times the norm of the inverse of x."

||X|| * ||X^-1||

for the matrix

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 1, 1],
               [2, 2, 1],
               [3, 3, 0]])

print np.linalg.cond(a)
```

1.84814479698e+16

```
print np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(a))
```

2.027453660713377e+17

Where is the mistake in my computation?

Thanks!

Comment: The matrix singular - 0 det, inf inverse etc.

Comment: Can't reproduce. My Python/Numpy raises `LinAlgError("Singular matrix")` when I call `inv(a)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to compute the condition using the Frobenius Norm definition. That is an optional parameter to the condition computation.

```
print(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(a)))
print(np.linalg.cond(a, p='fro'))
```

Produces

```
2.02745366071e+17
2.02745366071e+17
```

Answer (score 7):

[`norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)  uses the Frobenius norm for matrix by default,when cond uses 2-norm:

```
In [347]: np.linalg.cond(a)
Out[347]: 38.198730775206172

In [348]:np.linalg.norm(a,2)*np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(a),2)
Out[348]: 38.198730775206243

In [349]: np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(a))
Out[349]: 39.29814570824248
```

Comment: I didn't know `np.linalg.norm` understands operator norms! (+1)

Comment: Thanks, the explanation was very helpful! However, I found that  `np.linalg.cond(a,2) = np.linalg.norm(a,2)*np.linalg.norm(np.linalg.inv(a),2) != np.linalg.cond(a)`

Comment: Just rounding issues. probably operations are not exactly done iin the same order.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy [cond()](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8090) is currently buggy. There will come a time when we will fix it but for now if you are doing this for linear equation solutions you can use SciPy `linalg.solve` which will either produce an error for exact singularity or a warning if reciprocal condition number is below threshold and nothing if the array is invertible.